# Получить состояние главного сетевого соединения

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Как я понял **Windows** показывает состояние ГЛАВНОЙ сети в трее, по которой идет выход в интернет.

Это выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Еще может быть значок **Wi-Fi** с уровнем сигнала.
Так вот как эту информацию получать программно на **C#**?

Comment: Оно ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: не существует понятия ГЛАВНАЯ сеть. Логика данного значка следующая - есть  хотя бы одно активное WiFi соединение, показываем его, не важно, есть там интернет или нет, есть хотя бы одно активное проводное соединение, но нет активного WiFi, показываем проводное соединение. Если на всех соединениях отсутствует выход в интернет - добавляем к значку восклицательный знак, нет ни одного соединения - показываем проводное соединение и крестик. Всю эту информацию можно получить опросив все зарегистрированные в системе сетевые контроллеры.